# Ninject Interception at Namespace level?

Tags: ninject, ninject-interception

Is their a way to set up interception with the Ninject.Extensions.Interception extension so it applies it to all classes in a Namespace or assembly?

Currenlty i have to do it per class like this

```
  Kernel.Bind<MyClass>().ToSelf().Intercept().With<ILoggerAspect>();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Ninject.Extensions.Conventions` should take care of this (though it doesn't influence any explicit `Bind`ings you may have not generated via the conventions module).

See [the Ninject.Extensions.Conventions wiki](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki).